# apache order of authorization

Tags: authentication, apache-http-server, authorization

I have the following config snippet in apache 2.4

```
  <LocationMatch ^/[...]>
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "[...]"
     AuthBasicProvider ldap
     AuthLDAPUrl "..."
     Require ldap-filter ...

     Require ip 127.0.0.1 ...
  </LocationMatch>
```

and it works pertty much as expected except if a user both authenticates and comes from the allowed IP list auth data seems to be ignored, i.e. AUTH_USER is not set for CGI

Is there a way to tell Apache in which oerder to try the Require directives, i.e. to first try verifying basic auth and only consider IP addresses if that fails?

thanks